# Criação de componente Global Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Boa tarde..

Estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar criar um componente global com VUEJS..

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import Menu from '@/components/template/Menu';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component = ('app-menu', Menu)

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <app-menu></app-menu>

    <Toolbar />

    <v-content>
      <Carousel />
    </v-content>

    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Toolbar from "@/components/template/Toolbar";
import Carousel from "@/components/widgets/Carousel";
import Footer from "@/components/template/Footer";

export default {
  components: {Toolbar, Carousel, Footer },
};
</script>
```

**ERRO:**

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

--->  at src/App.vue

Comment: Vue.component = ('app-menu', Menu) troca pra Vue.component('app-menu', Menu) to achando que  é essa sintaxe que está incorreta

Comment: Muito obrigado, era realmente esse o problema.

Comment: Blz, vou responder a pergunta

Comment: Só ler a documentação: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Answer (score 1):

A sua sintaxe do método `Vue.component` está incorreta, a sintaxe correta é `Vue.component('app-menu', Menu)`